# Multiple language using fb:restricted-to

Tags: facebook, restriction

I am trying to make a page in multiple languages, so that visitors will get it in their local language.

I am using fb:restricted-to but when I am making a testpage, that should show content for my own country, it does not work:

My code looks like this:

```
<fb:restricted-to location="dk">You are living in Denmark
    <fb:else>You are not living in Denmark</fb:else>
</fb:restricted-to>
```

But it says that I am not living in Denmark

Answer (score 1):

FBML is deprecated and Apps that use it will no longer work starting June 1st, 2012. So don't use it at all. You can get the users locale from the signed request in PHP that get's passed to your App when the user visits it. You can read about it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/